# Migrate large postgresql database (windows -> linux)

Tags: postgresql, migration, pg-restore

I have a "large" PostgreSQL (9.6 with timescale plugin) database (about 1Tb). And would like to migrate it to a Linux machine. The naive approach would be pg_dump and pg_restore. 
(Not sure how long that might take on a powerful machine with SSD on both sides, maybe you have an idea?)

Just wanted to ask if this is the way to go or if there might be a better more convenient solution. What I saw so far were pgBackRestore and barman.

I'm asking this question since I already had some trouble migrating a MongoDB database which took really very long. So now I would like to avoid errors : )

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: Maybe just what one might expect. Lets say if pg_restore/dump takes more then 24hours then I would go with a complete different approach. Something like fetching and inserting the most recent data (which is relevant) and doing restore/dump on small tables only.

Comment: Using `pg_upgrade` with the `--link` option will be the fastest solution. Make sure you have a backup before doing that.

Comment: @horse_with_no_name Don't understand your comment. The asker wants to move PG from Windows to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the *directory format* (`-F d`) of `pg_dump`, you can parallelize dump and restore, which will help if there are several large tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was going to use the -Fc command, which would take much longer. Will post later how long it took!

Comment: As promised here a short update. The -F d command worked and took about 1 hour to dump and a bit longer to restore. Unfortunately, timescale had some problems with the -j command. So I ended up using -Fc as a command. All together it took more the 6 hours...and after that some manual work. In the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup a streaming replica on your Linux machine. Then promote it. Use `pg_basebackup` to take the initial copy, but you can do this while the master is running. Promoting the replica to be the new master will only take seconds, if that.